# Guardar elementos ordenados en pyton

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, python-3.7

```
import random
ordenada = []
for i in range(1000):
     print(random.randint(-1000, 1000))
     
     for recorrido in range(1, len(ordenada)):
        for posicion in range(len(ordenada) - recorrido):
            if ordenada[posicion]>ordenada[posicion + 1]:
                temp= ordenada[posicion]
                ordenada[posicion] = ordenada[posicion + 1]
                ordenada[posicion + 1] = temp
                print (ordenada=[])
```

Comment: Hola Asc. C.  puedes dar mas detalle de lo que necesitas, cual es tu problema?

Comment: # Utiliza la biblioteca random para generar 1000 números aleatorios entre -1000
# y 1000. Posteriormente ordénalos de forma ascendente. Guarda la lista final en
# una variable llamada "ordenada"

No hay que usar la función sort o sorted

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
tablero = [0] * 2001
for i in range(1000):
    valor = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    print(valor)
    tablero[valor + 1000] = 1
```

`tablero` es una lista (arreglo) de 2001 elementos. El primer elemento (`tablero[0]`) corresponde al valor -1000; el segundo elemento, al valor -999, y asi sucesivamente.

Usaremos `tablero` para ir marcando los valores que retorna `random.randint`. Como los indices parten de cero y no de -1000, *corremos* el indice en 1000 posiciones.

Luego de generados los 1.000 valores, recorremos `tablero` desde el primer elemento (correspondiente al valor `-1000`) revisando si vale cero (nunca apareció) o uno (el valor apareció al menos una vez).

Cada vez que detectemos un valor que si apareció, lo agregamos a la lista `ordenada`

```
ordenada = []
for i in range(len(tablero)):
    if tablero[i] == 1:
        ordenada.append(i - 1000)
print(ordenada)
```

**Demo**

Hare la demo con 10 valores, para poder revisarla con facilidad, cambiando

```
for i in range(1000):
```

por

```
for i in range(10):
```

produce:

```
-254
-204
-523
205
-596
-601
463
368
472
716
[-601, -596, -523, -254, -204, 205, 368, 463, 472, 716]
```